# Error In using Microsoft.EnterpriseLibrary5.0

Tags: c#, enterprise-library-5

I want to use EnterpriseLibrary 5.0 dlls for logging in my project.
For this I have added these dll to my references:

```
Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common
Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data
Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging
Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Database
```

And then I write this:

```
using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data; 
using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration; 
using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging;
```

And then I wrote:

```
LogEntry logEntry = new LogEntry();
logEntry.Message = "Message";
Logger.Write(logEntry);
```

But when my code executed, I get this exception at the last line:

> Activation error occured while trying to get instance of type
>   LogWriter, key ""

that has this InnerException:

> Resolution of the dependency failed, type =
>   \"Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.LogWriter\", name =
>   \"(none)\".\r\nException occurred while: Calling constructor
>   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.TraceListeners.FlatFileTraceListener(System.String
>   fileName, System.String header, System.String footer,
>   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Formatters.ILogFormatter
>   formatter).\r\nException is: IOException - The device is not
>   ready.\r\n\r\n-----------------------------------------------\r\nAt
>   the time of the exception, the container was:\r\n\r\n  Resolving
>   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.LogWriterImpl,LogWriter.**default**
>   (mapped from Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.LogWriter,
>   (none))\r\n  Resolving parameter \"structureHolder\" of constructor
>   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.LogWriterImpl(Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.LogWriterStructureHolder
>   structureHolder,
>   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Instrumentation.ILoggingInstrumentationProvider
>   instrumentationProvider,
>   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.ILoggingUpdateCoordinator
>   updateCoordinator)\r\n    Resolving
>   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.LogWriterStructureHolder,LogWriterStructureHolder.**default**
>   (mapped from
>   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.LogWriterStructureHolder,
>   (none))\r\n    Resolving parameter \"traceSources\" of constructor
>   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.LogWriterStructureHolder(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[[Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Filters.ILogFilter,
>   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]] filters,
>   System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[[System.String, mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]
>   traceSourceNames,
>   System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[[Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.LogSource,
>   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]] traceSources,
>   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.LogSource
>   allEventsTraceSource,
>   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.LogSource
>   notProcessedTraceSource,
>   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.LogSource
>   errorsTraceSource, System.String defaultCategory, System.Boolean
>   tracingEnabled, System.Boolean logWarningsWhenNoCategoriesMatch,
>   System.Boolean revertImpersonation)\r\n      Resolving
>   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.LogSource,Trace\r\n
>
>   Resolving parameter \"traceListeners\" of constructor
>   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.LogSource(System.String
>   name,
>   System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[[System.Diagnostics.TraceListener,
>   System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]] traceListeners,
>   System.Diagnostics.SourceLevels level, System.Boolean autoFlush,
>   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Instrumentation.ILoggingInstrumentationProvider
>   instrumentationProvider)\r\n        Resolving
>   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.TraceListeners.ReconfigurableTraceListenerWrapper,Flat
>   FileTrace Listener (mapped from System.Diagnostics.TraceListener, Flat
>   FileTrace Listener)\r\n        Resolving parameter
>   \"wrappedTraceListener\" of constructor
>   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.TraceListeners.ReconfigurableTraceListenerWrapper(System.Diagnostics.TraceListener
>   wrappedTraceListener,
>   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.ILoggingUpdateCoordinator
>   coordinator)\r\n          Resolving
>   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.TraceListeners.FlatFileTraceListener,Flat
>   FileTrace Listener‌implementation (mapped from
>   System.Diagnostics.TraceListener, Flat FileTrace
>   Listener‌implementation)\r\n          Calling constructor
>   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.TraceListeners.FlatFileTraceListener(System.String
>   fileName, System.String header, System.String footer,
>   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Formatters.ILogFormatter
>   formatter)

And it has this InnerException:

> The device is not ready.

How to I can resolve this error?

Comment: Have you configured Logging using either XML of the Fluent Configuration API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error was from app.config file.
I'd use a same app.config file that has some error.
When I used an app.config that creates with EntLib application, My error resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Read the following article: [How to configure and use Microsoft Enterprise Library 5 for logging](http://www.gonetdotnet.info/posts/configure-and-use-enterprise-library-5-logging)